# How to implement a recursive with clause in larger sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a large sql query involving some recursive with clauses and I'm in need of some ideas on how to "connect" them with the rest of the query.

First, what I want to accomplish. I have a table like this:

```
ID      NAME            FOLDER
1       object1         folderA
2       object2         folderB
3       object3         folderC
4       folderA         folderD
5       folderB         folderD
6       folderD         folderE
7       folderC         NULL
...
```

So, objects are listed here and the folders these objects are placed in. What I'd like to know now, as part of a bigger query, is an object placed in a specific folder or (thats where the recursive part come in) in a subfolder? Like: Is object1 located in (or in a subfolder of) folderE? If so, I'd like all the subfolders listed.

I managed to get an answer through a recursive with clause

```
WITH recursive_statement (id, folder) AS
(
SELECT name, folder
FROM table
WHERE name = 'object1'
UNION ALL
SELECT t.name, t.folder
FROM table t
INNER JOIN recursive_statement rs
ON t.name = rs.folder
)
SELECT *
FROM recursive_statement
```

This will give me a very good result. I.e. for object1 I get

```
NAME            FOLDER
object1         folderA
folderA         folderD
folderD         folderE
folderE         NULL
```

But I have trouble inserting this result in my bigger query. I can not figure out how to get the name of the object into the with clause. The object name in question is defined inside the with clause and can not be set from oustide. If I call the recursive statement from outside with "WHERE name = 'object1'" then I get 1 line (of course) saying 'object1 -> folderA'. That doesn't help me.

What I would need is to be able to get the object name inside the statement. Like so:

```
WITH recursive_statement (...) AS
(
-- my recursive statement which takes the object name in question from outside
)
SELECT *
FROM recursive_statement
-- Somehow get the object name inside the with clause from here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the original name in the cte and query that:

```
WITH recursive_statement AS ( 
SELECT name as OriginalName, name, folder 
FROM table 

UNION ALL 

SELECT rs.OriginalName, t.name, t.folder 
FROM table t 
INNER JOIN recursive_statement rs 
ON t.name = rs.folder 
 ) 

SELECT * 
FROM recursive_statement
Where OriginalName = 'object1'
```

The recursion only happens when the cte is being queried, so performance shouldn't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine several Common Table Expressions (CTE) and use previous CTE in the next. Something like this.

```
with cte1 as (
   select something from someTable
   where someCondition=1
),
recursive_statement (...) AS (
   select ... from otherTable
   where something in (select something from cte1)
)
select *
from recursive_statement
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd prefer the solution from HoneyBadger though, because it seems to be the most flexible one in my case.